# C# conditional based on property

Tags: c#, object

I have the following classes

```
class ClassA : SuperClass { }
class ClassB : SuperClass { }
class ClassC : SuperClass { }
class SuperClass
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Property1 { get; set; }
    string Property2 { get; set; }
    List<string> Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

When a condition is met, I have to override one, two or all of the properties in any of the classes (A, B, C) and I have to know that the properties were overridden and which ones where. 
So I created this interface that should be implemented by SuperClass.

```
public interface IOverride
{
    string OverrideProperty1 { get; set; }
    string OverrideProperty2 { get; set; }
    List<string> OrderedProperty3 { get; set; }
}
```

How can I know if a property was overridden without having to create a boolean for each property.
Or should I go for a different approach?

**EDIT**

ClassA, ClassB and ClassC data come from a specific source and for each of the objects I get information from another source. If the new source has values I need to stored them and override the original ones.

Something like

```
var dataList = GetClassesData() as List<SuperClass>;
var newData = GetNewData() as object[];

foreach (var data in dataList)
{
    if (newData.Contains(o => o.Id == data.Id))
    {
        data.Property1 = newData[Id].Property1;
        data.Property2 = newData[Id].Property2;
        data.Property3 = newData[Id].Property3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Overriding (in the C# terminology) is never conditional - or rather, it's not conditional at execution-time, but at compilation time. It would really help if you'd give more detail of what you mean and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: A more concrete example of your problem would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding itself is not intent to be conditional, what *can* be conditional, is the `value` of the property you return from overridden class.

Comment: In a roundabout way, I think you're saying, for this kind of logic, you can't use auto properties, you'll have to do it longhand.

Comment: @JeffWatkins: that is *consiquence*. But yes, with autoproperties, I don't see how one can implement that.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```
if(typeof(ClassA).GetMethod("Property1").DeclaringType == typeof(SuperClass)){
     //This method was overridden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your edited question right, you could put it like that:

```
public interface IOverride
{
    string StandardProperty1 { get; set; }
    string StandardProperty2 { get; set; }
    List<string> StandardProperty3 { get; set; }

    string OverrideProperty1 { get; set; }
    string OverrideProperty2 { get; set; }
    List<string> OrderedProperty3 { get; set; }
}

class ClassA : SuperClass { }
class ClassB : SuperClass { }
class ClassC : SuperClass { }
class SuperClass : IOverrideProperty
{
    string StandardProperty1 { get; set; }
    string StandardProperty2 { get; set; }
    List<string> StandardProperty3 { get; set; }

    string OverrideProperty1 { get; set; }
    string OverrideProperty2 { get; set; }
    List<string> OrderedProperty3 { get; set; }

    string Property1 
    { 
        get
        {
            if (condition)
                return OverrideProperty1;
            else
                return StandardProperty1;
        } 
        set
        {
             if (condition)
                OverrideProperty1 = value;
            else
                StandardProperty1 = value;
        }

        //Same for Property2 and 3
}
```

You can now set both Properties and your condition will decide wich one is returned or set.